# Create a column based on first row of each sorted group in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to group a dataframe based on two columns and sort each group based on another column and then create new column for each group based on first row of each group!(col3 is date in my dataset)

dataframe:

```
col1            col2         col3
A               0            2.0
A               0            1.0
A               0            3.0
A               1            3.0
A               1            4.0
B               0            3.0
B               0            1.0
B               1            1.0
B               1            1.0
```

output:

```
col1            col2         col3           col4
A               0            2.0        1.0
A               0            1.0        1.0
A               0            3.0        1.0
A               1            3.0        3.0
A               1            4.0        3.0
B               0            3.0        1.0
B               0            1.0        1.0
B               1            0.0        0.0
B               1            1.0        0.0
```

I tried this :

```
active_users = active_users.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('col3')).transform('first')
```

and got this error:

> ```
> TypeError: first() missing 1 required positional argument: 'offset'
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create such column with:

```
df['col4'] = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2'])['col3'].transform('min')
```

Since the first value of the sorted items is the minimum. Usually it will be better to use the minimum over the first item of the sorted list, since calculating the minimum can be done in *O(n)*. For sorting it depends on the algorithm itself, since there are lazy sorting algorithms that could sometimes obtain the first element in *O(n)* as well, but I think `'min'` makes it more clear what you aim to do.

For the given sample dataframe we will then obtain:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['A']*5 + ['B']*4, 'col2': [0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1], 'col3': [2,1,3,3,4,3,1,0,1.0]})
>>> df
  col1  col2  col3
0    A     0   2.0
1    A     0   1.0
2    A     0   3.0
3    A     1   3.0
4    A     1   4.0
5    B     0   3.0
6    B     0   1.0
7    B     1   0.0
8    B     1   1.0
>>> df['col4'] = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2'])['col3'].transform('min')
>>> df
  col1  col2  col3  col4
0    A     0   2.0   1.0
1    A     0   1.0   1.0
2    A     0   3.0   1.0
3    A     1   3.0   3.0
4    A     1   4.0   3.0
5    B     0   3.0   1.0
6    B     0   1.0   1.0
7    B     1   0.0   0.0
8    B     1   1.0   0.0
```